# pointer to 2d int array vs pointer to 2d char a. treated differently

Tags: c

If I have this

```
 int (*p)[2];
```

and try to do

```
 *(*(p))=5;
```

it will throw segFault. it should.

But if I have

```
  char (*p)[2];
  *(*(p))=5; //works
  *(*(p+1))=7; //works
```

Can some one explain why pointer to `2d char array` treated differently than `pointer to 2 d int array` in C

Comment: Dereferencing `NULL` (if `p` is allocated globally) or using value of non-initialized non-static local variable invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Dereferencing an invalid pointer leads to *undefined behavior*. It might cause a crash, it might seem to work, or it might set your cat on fire. Just don't do it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Dereferencing an invalid pointer leads to undefined behavior.` does `Dereferencing` means `assigning` to ...?

Comment: No, it's the use of the dereference operator `*`. The variable `p` is a pointer. You never explicitly make it point anywhere which means it will eaither be a null pointer, or have an indeterminate value. Neither are valid pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if I want to dynamically create array (extending size) or `pointer to 2 d array` then the only right thing is with realoc? is this correct but thats too inefficient

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think it can be solved with a pointer to an array of two integers? What are you going to do with this pointer? And what "efficiency" requirements do you have? What measurements and profiling have you made to determine that what you're doing is one of the top two (or possibly three) bottlenecks in your program? Please post a new question about the *actual* problem you need help with instead, as this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am creating a simple program in `C` that simply find the largest contagiously same gap sub-array  I like to do it in single loop. so for that I either use `realoc` but I dont want to use realoc since someone told me in real work server applications we dont use realoc was that in correct?

Comment: If you need to reallocate memory, then you don't really have any other choice. There are ways to minimize the number of reallocations (like always allocate more than is needed at the moment), but some times there's no way to avoid it.

Comment: On an unrelated note, for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i) ` is *exactly* equal to `p[i] `. That means `*(*(p)) ` is the same as `p[0][0]`. The latter is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, *works* (apparently) is one of the possible outcomes of an ill-formed program. The pointer has no memory assigned to it, [dereferencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955198/6865932) is undefined behavior.

It can also make the compiler shoot you down, as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67336360/6865932).

As for the works part, [here you can see it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/q56znej8b), (139 return code is a segmentation fault btw).

Comment: can I excessively use realoc to extend the sizeof `int (*p)[N+1]`

Comment: see my comment below question

Comment: @user786 you can use realloc as many times as you want, within the memory you have available, of course, so I don't see a problem there, but you would need to show the code, an MRE of it.