# Negative float type value from python (pybind11) cannot cast correctly in C++

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I would like to pass a negative float value from python using pybind11 to a cpp function where that negative value will be statically cast to `uint32_t` type and do further processing. There, I am facing a very weird issue that after casting the resutl returns ZERO.

- my cpp function is like as follows:

```cpp
void do_calc(double value){
    // while calling this function from python the following line
    //print the correct negative value, eg: -6 or -6.1
    std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;

    // But this is the error case. While calling C++ function alone,
    //it results the correct uint32_t value. But from python calling it gives me zero
    std::cout << "value: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(value) << std::endl;
}
```

- Pybind code is more general way, I am only giving here the pseudo one

```cpp
.def("do_calc",<double>(&CPP_CLASS_NAME::do_calc))
```

- I am taking a string input from python end and convert this to float and call cpp the function.

Any idea what would be the cause of it?

Comment: undefined behaviour, the environments can do whatever they feel adequate. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions (and while that page is "implicit conversion", the 3rd case of [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) brings you there).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541200/is-the-behaviour-of-casting-a-negative-double-to-unsigned-int-defined-in-the-c-s

Comment: Funny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336264/casting-a-negative-const-double-to-unsigned-results-in-0-while-non-const-double